# unable to build FFmpeg in buildozer or p4a

Tags: ffmpeg, buildozer, p4a

[INFO]:    Building ffmpeg for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/suryaveda/PycharmProjects/music_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg
[INFO]:    -> running configure --disable-everything --enable-openssl --enable-nonfree --enable-pro...(and 818 more)

**Exception in thread background thread for pid 85730:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1662, in wrap
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2606, in background_thread
handle_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2304, in fn
return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

STDOUT:
**tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified**
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

**Buildozer.spec**

requirements=python3,kivy,ffpyplayer,openssl,ffpyplayer_codecs